# Express logarithmic integral as geometric mean of two functions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, means

The offset logarithmic integral is defined as:

$$ Li(x)=\int_2^x \frac{1}{\log(t)} ~dt$$

I want to express $Li(x)$ as the geometric mean of two functions $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ s.t. $h(x)\ne f(x).$

That is, $$ Li(x)=\sqrt{f(x)h(x)}.$$

Also, I would like $\lim_{x\to \infty}|f(x)-Li(x)|=1$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}|h(x)-Li(x)|=1.$

Can it be done?

Comment: I suppose you lok for $f$ and $h$ not being dilations of $Li(x)$, isn't it? If not, take $f(x)=2Li(x)$ and $h(x)=Li(x)/2$, for instance.

Comment: @TitoEliatron I added a stipulation.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Li}{Li}$ We can, let $f(x) = 1 + \Li(x)$ and $h(x) = \frac{Li^2(x)}{f(x)}$. But that's rather silly and pointless. Have you any practical purpose you want this for, or is it just for kix?

Comment: Just curious. Thanks for that example. I found one more example